# Como eu posso fazer uma soma no R de forma que ele some apenas os valores e ignore os NA's, mas onde há NA's ele mostre?

Tags: r, ggplot2, soma

```
base3 <- base2.2 %>%
  mutate(mês = month(data),
         ano = year(data)) %>%
  group_by(mês,ano) %>%
  summarise(qt_mosquitos = sum(na.omit(qt_mosquitos)))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

saída:

```
base2.2 <-
  structure(list(
    nome_local = c("centro de saude", "centro de saude", 
                   "centro de saude", "centro de saude", "centro de saude", "centro de saude", 
                   "centro de saude", "centro de saude", "centro de saude", "centro de saude", 
                   "centro de saude", "centro de saude", "centro de saude", "centro de saude", 
                   "centro de saude", "centro de saude", "ictb", "ictb", "ictb", 
                   "ictb"), 
    num_aspiração = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), 
    ano = c(2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
            2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021), 
    mês = c("fev", "fev", "fev", "fev", 
            "fev", "fev", "fev", "fev", "fev", "fev", "fev", "fev", "fev", 
            "fev", "fev", "fev", "mai", "mai", "mai", "mai"), 
    data = structure(c(1614211200, 1614211200, 1614211200, 1614211200, 
                       1614211200, 1614211200, 1614211200, 1614211200, 
                       1614211200, 1614211200, 1614211200, 1614211200, 
                       1614211200, 1614211200, 1614211200, 1614211200, 
                       1620259200, 1620259200, 1620259200, 1620259200), 
                     tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
    semana = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 18, 18, 18, 18), 
    amb_aspiração = c("intra", "intra", "intra", 
                      "intra", "intra", "intra", "intra", "intra", "peri", "peri", 
                      "peri", "peri", "peri", "peri", "peri", "peri", "intra", 
                      "intra", "intra", "intra"), 
    aspiração_pos = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    num_mosquitos = c(9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
                      18, 18, 18, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    coordx = c(679518, 679518, 679518, 679518, 679518, 
               679518, 679518, 679518, 679543, 679543, 679543, 679543, 679543, 
               679543, 679543, 679543, 679922, 679922, 679922, 679922), 
    coordy = c(7468991, 7468991, 7468991, 7468991, 7468991, 7468991, 
               7468991, 7468991, 7469022, 7469022, 7469022, 7469022, 7469022, 
               7469022, 7469022, 7469022, 7469005, 7469005, 7469005, 7469005), 
    especies = c("aeg_F", "aeg_M", "albo_F", "albo_M", "scap_F", 
                 "scap_M", "culex_F", "culex_M", "aeg_F", "aeg_M", "albo_F", 
                 "albo_M", "scap_F", "scap_M", "culex_F", "culex_M", "aeg_F", 
                 "aeg_M", "albo_F", "albo_M"), 
    qt_mosquitos = c(1, 5, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 14, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    genero = c("Fêmea", "Macho", "Fêmea", "Macho", "Fêmea", "Macho", "Fêmea", 
               "Macho", "Fêmea", "Macho", "Fêmea", "Macho", "Fêmea", "Macho", 
               "Fêmea", "Macho", "Fêmea", "Macho", "Fêmea", "Macho"), 
    especiessep = c("Aegypti", "Aegypti", "Albopictus", "Albopictus", 
                    "Scapularis", "Scapularis", "Culex", "Culex", "Aegypti", 
                    "Aegypti", "Albopictus", "Albopictus", "Scapularis", 
                    "Scapularis", "Culex", "Culex", "Aegypti", 
                    "Aegypti", "Albopictus", "Albopictus")), 
    row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

eu queria fazer com que o gráfico fosse descontínuo à medida que os NA's aparecem, mas eu não consigo somar sem tirar os NA's. Se há algum NA e eu somo, esta aparece como "NA" mesmo que haja outros valores.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, dê uma olhada [neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6700/como-fazer-uma-pergunta-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r/6701#6701) (principalmente no uso da função `dput`) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Comment: Pode, por favor, editar a pergunta com a saída de `dput(base2.2)` ou, se a base for muito grande, de `dput(head(base2.2, 20))`? Outra coisa, não use `na.omit` em `sum`, a forma correta é `sum(qt_mosquitos, na.rm = TRUE)`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas, coloquei!

Comment: Não há NAs nos dados que postou. Por favor, edite a questão para conter uma amostra de dados que seja representativa. Inclua também as bibliotecas que está carregando para rodar seu código.

Comment: Creio não ser possível fazer isso que você pretende. Veja que o eixo X contém valores numéricos, e NA não é numérico. Converter NA para "0" não é suficiente para exibir isso no gráfico. Considerando que um NA é ausência de valor e que "0" pode ser entendido com "sem valor".

Answer (score -2):

Use na.rm=T para ignorar os NA